# Prove that $\tau = \mathcal{P}(Y) \cup \{X\}$ is a topology over $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a infinite set, $x_0 \notin Y$, and define $X = Y \cup \{x_0\}$. Prove that $\tau = \mathcal{P}(Y) \cup \{X\}$ is a topology on $X$.

I don't see why the hypothesis "$Y$ infinite" is necessary for $\tau$ to be a topology. Am I missing something?

Comment: Since you haven't shown any attempt, it's difficult to answer the question "Am I missing something? "

Comment: Yeah, $Y$ infinite doesn't matter.

Comment: Sometimes, in a sequence of questions, the assumptions in an early are actually needed for a later question in the sequence, but, just in this question alone, the condition that $Y$ is infinite is unnecessary.

Comment: I proved all the properties for this to be a topology over X, but I didn't use this assumption for Y, that's why I got confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the hypothesis is not necessary. You can prove it for $Y$ any set.

*Proof:* Clearly, $\emptyset, X\in\tau$.

Let $\{U_i\}_i\subset\tau$. Then either all $U_i\in\mathcal P(Y)$ or there exists some ${i_0}$ such that $U_{i_0}=X$. In the first case, $\bigcup_i U_i \subset Y$, so $\bigcup_i U_i \in \tau$; in the second case, $\bigcup_i U_i=X\in\tau$, so the union of open sets is open.

Finally, if $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}\subset\tau$, then either all $U_i=X$ or there exists some $i_0$ such that $U_{i_0}≠X$ (so $U_{i_0}\subset Y$). In the first case, $\bigcap_i U_i = X\in\tau$; in the second case, $\bigcap_i U_i\subset U_{i_0}\subset Y$, so $\bigcap_i U_i\in\tau$, hence the (finite) intersection of open sets is open.